# Ck-editor field rendering in HTML to PDF template in Django

Tags: python, django-templates, jinja2, ckeditor, rendering

CK-editor field not rendering in HTML to PDF template, in my django web application.

Using ck-editor in my Django application.

models.py

full_question = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True)

If I stored text and image both in this field or one thing at one time it's working perfectly fine and displaying the content through rendering in template like this
in the template.

```
             {% for question in questions %}

              <tr>
                <td class="firstTd">{{ questions.start_index|add:forloop.counter0 }}</td>
                <td class="questionTd">
                  {{question.category.group}}
                </td>
                <td class="questionTd">
                  {{question.subject}}
                </td>
                <td class="questionTd">
                    
                  {{question.full_question | safe}}

                   width="100px" height="80px" alt="">
                   
                </td>
                </tr>
             {% endfor %}
```

but when I render this in HTML to PDF it display only text, if I add image in this field
full_question = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True)
image not render in HTML to PDF template